# How to deploy Bitlocker via WDS

Tags: windows, windows-7, wds, bitlocker

Let's say I have a notebook without anything, no software, no operating system. Now I want to install Windows (with some programs) from my WDS. Which works just fine, but how do I tell Windows to autmomatically encrypt the hard drive via Bitlocker within that process?

OS is Windows 7 + Server 2012 R2.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you tried running manage-bde commands post install, for example?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the BitLocker package in the Image Builder Wizard and then make sure that you check the `Create separate system partition` checkbox in the wizard so that BitLocker can function correctly.

You can find more info about this [at an MSDN blog post, here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/archive/2010/05/03/mass-deployment-and-bitlocker-the-gotcha.aspx).